# Retrieving a set of coordinates from a dataset of physical addresses using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dataset

Using a set of addresses in the format `{Street}, {suburb}, {city}`

for example: **72 Victoria Street West, Auckland Central, Auckland**

*Is it possible to pass a ***set*** of addresses into the google maps api and return a ***set*** of the corresponding longitudes and latitudes of each address?*

for example the above address would return **[-36.8483798,174.7611771]**

I know that the default limit on api calls is 2500.

There are a lot of addresses **(+5000)** I want to pass to the api.

Currently I am thinking of using a javascript function to iterate over every address individually and pass it to the api but this seems inefficient and will exceed the call limit before it finishes.

From my research online and through the maps api documentation I have not been able to find an answer.

**Please let me know if I can clarify this question further.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass a set of addresses in one request. You can pass only one address.

If you need more than 2500 daily requests Google offers enable Billing and pay $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits